# key Combination in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

**How to write code in actionscript 3 using combinations of keys for example: If I press the key combination Ctrl + A, then `trace("You pressed the key combination Ctrl + A "); or
Ctrl+B

```
trace("You pressed key combination of Ctrl+B");
```

Comment: i know how it combination                                                       if (event.keyCode == 17 || event.keyCode == 68) { trace("Pressed Ctrl or d");} but i need key combination of Ctrl+D not Ctrl or d, i have put && instead of ||, but it does not work, what can i do for?

Answer (score 3):

```
//add global keyboard listener somewhere in init section
stage.addEventListenter(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey)
    {
        trace("You pressed Ctrl-A");
    }
}
```

Ctrl, alt and shift keys are special case, their status is sent with every keyboard event. If you need to detect something like A + Enter, you need to track pressed and released keys in an array (or vector.)

Comment: Don't you just love it, when this happens?